# Getting "None" in webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am really new to python, but I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to web-scrape CSGO skins' prices (specifically, sell). However, I am getting None. I suspect it is because two lines of the HTML code is the same, but one number is the requests, and the other number is the number I need: The sell number. Can someone help with this? I am specifically looking at the new challenger capsules. If anyone can help, that would be very much appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URLChallengerCapsule = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/2020%20RMR%20Challengers'
page = requests.get(URLChallengerCapsule)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='market_commodity_buyrequests')

ChallengerCapsulePrice = results.find('span', class_= 'market_commodity_orders_header_promote')

print(ChallengerCapsulePrice)
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URLChallengerCapsule = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/2020%20RMR%20Challengers'
page = requests.get(URLChallengerCapsule)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='market_commodity_buyrequests')

ChallengerCapsulePrice = results.find('span', class_= 'market_commodity_orders_header_promote')

print(ChallengerCapsulePrice)
```

Comment: Does the site populate it's content with javascript? If so you'll need to use something other than bs.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup does not work with data populated synchronously with JavaScript.

When you use cURL to load this page (which does not support JavaScript), you can see that this `div` is empty:

```
curl -s https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/2020%20RMR%20Challengers | grep market_commodity_buyrequests -A 1
    <div class="market_commodity_order_summary" id="market_commodity_buyrequests">
    </div>
```

There is a good list of [headless browsers here](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers). You can find some of them in Python that do support Javascript. Some other lists online are probably more up to date.

Comment: Just a question, I've seen some youtube videos about using BeautifulSoup to grab game names in steam. Do prices not work either then?

Comment: I doubled checked with cURl and not, they add the prices asynchronously with JavaScript so you cannot use `BeautifulSoup` for this purpose.

Comment: I have some more questions about headless browsers. So do I download one that supports Javascript, then paste my code, then it should work? What do I need to update in my code?

Comment: you can find examples on how to use the one you will be choosing.

Comment: Is my code alright, or do I need to change it? You mentioned that BS does not work, so what do I have to do to change my code? I'm fairly new so if I need to change my code please let me know and why.